# Swift conditional binding

Tags: ios, swift, enums, switch-statement, uikit

I am building an iOS app using Swift.  I have three `UIViewControllers` and an enum for when I want to present them using a segue.

```
class a: UIViewController {}
class b: UIViewController {}
class c: UIViewController {}
```

I am writing a function to iterate over them and if c is the current one then I need to set a property. Then use my instance of a,b,c later.

```
// Segues 
func segue(sender: Button) {
    let title = sender.destination!
    switch title {
    case .NewWorkout:
        let VC: NewWorkout = NewWorkout()
    case .Home:
        let VC: Home = Home()
    case .Preview:
        let VC: WorkoutPreview = WorkoutPreview()
        VC.type = .allWorkouts
    } // 1

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) // 2
}
```

The errors I am getting are `Expected expression in assignment` on the line with a 1 and `Use of unresolved identifier "VC"` on the line 2.  I understand that my issue is VC is created in the switch statement and isn't available outside of its scoop. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the `VC` variable *before* the switch statement:

```
let VC : UIViewController

switch title {
    case .NewWorkout:
        VC = NewWorkout()
    case .Home:
        VC = Home()
    case .Preview:
        let workoutPreview = WorkoutPreview()
        workoutPreview.type = .allWorkouts
        VC = workoutPreview
}

self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Note that you can declare `VC` as a (non-optional) constant with `let`
if all possible enumeration values are handled in the switch. If necessary, you can add a

```
    default:
       fatalError("Unexpected title")
```

Comment: I tried that `VC.type` doesn't have the property "type". I need to force downcast if I do this approach and don't know how to do that.

Comment: thank for the default idea but I don't like using them on switches over enums because then if I add a value xcode is like hey fix me here.

Comment: Yeah thanks man. I really appreciate the help, sorry for the delay in communication my month old son wasn't happy!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want something like this:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

enum ControllerType {
    case allWorkouts
}

class NewWorkoutController: UIViewController { }
class HomeController: UIViewController { }
class WorkoutPreviewController: UIViewController {
    var type: ControllerType?
}

enum Destination {
    case NewWorkout
    case Home
    case Preview

    var controller: UIViewController {
        switch self {
        case NewWorkout:
            return NewWorkoutController()
        case Home:
            return HomeController()
        case Preview:
            let vc = WorkoutPreviewController()
            vc.type = .allWorkouts
            return vc
        }
    }
}

class Button: UIButton {
    var destination: Destination?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    func segue(sender: Button) {
        if let vc = sender.destination?.controller {
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Martin already answered my question and I marked it as so. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are declaring `VC` inside the switch so when you use `VC` to segue it doesn't know what `VC` is. `VC` is out of scope for `presentViewController`. Here is one way you could do it instead:

```
func segue(sender: Button) {
    let title = sender.destination!
    var VC:UIViewController
    switch title {
        case .NewWorkout:
            VC = NewWorkout()
        case .Home:
            VC = Home()
        case .Preview:
            VC = WorkoutPreview()
            VC.type = .allWorkouts
    } // 1

    self.presentViewController(VC, animated: true, completion: nil) // 2
}
```

So now `VC` is in the same scope where `presentViewController` is being called.